# what JAR contains getPart() method?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to upload a file into mySQL database from apache 7.0 server . I have written html code to upload a file.

```
<form action="UploadValidate.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><font size="4" color="white">File Upload</font></legend><br/><br/>
    <font size="4" color="white"><b>
    <h3> Select File to Upload</h3> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="file"name="file" /><br/><br/>

    <center>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" /><br/><br/></center>

    </font>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is UploadValidate.jsp

```
      <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*,java.lang.String.*,com.oreilly.servlet.*"%>
      <%
       InputStream inputstream=null;
       String str=request.getParameter("file");
       Part filePart=request.getPart(str);
       out.println(filePart);
       if(filePart!=null){
           out.println(filePart.getName());
           out.println(filePart.getSize());
           out.println(filePart.getContentType());
           //output the inputstream of uploaded file
           inputstream=filePart.getInputStream();
        }
       else{
       out.println("cannot execute if condition");
        }
      %>
     <%
    try{
    String message=null;
    int id=123;
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Project";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","admin");
    String sql="INSERT INTO uploadfile(id,file) VALUES(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setInt(1,id);
    if(inputstream!=null){
        stmt.setBlob(2,inputstream);
    }
    int row=stmt.executeUpdate();
    if(row>0){
        out.print("<h3><font color=red> Success Welcome!!!!!<br><br> </font></h3>");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//session.setAttribute("Message",message);
//response.sendRedirect("Message.jsp");
   %>
```

The filePart object returns null eventhough i have selected a file to upload. It terminates if bolck and returns
                       "null cannot execute if condition" as output.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  Scriptlet code in JSPs went out of fashion in 1999.  Don't do this.  A debugger will show you quickly where you went wrong.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? There are many examples around he web. See http://corejavaexample.blogspot.fr/2013/04/how-to-upload-file-in-jsp.html for example, you see how to handle "multipart/form-data

Answer (score 3):

To answer the actual question, the reason you are getting a null return value is two-fold.  Firstly, the code:

```
   String str=request.getParameter("file");
   Part filePart=request.getPart(str);
```

should simply be

```
   Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
```

But, crucially, the `request.getPart` method is a Servlet 3.0 feature which requires use of a servlet (not a JSP file) annotated with [`@MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html).

However, the code is littered with bad practice.

As stated in the comments, using scriptlets has been discouraged for over a decade; you should use a servlet as some sort of controller first, and then forward (internally) to your JSP view using something like:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/view.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

The `<font>` and `<center>` HTML elements have also been deprecated for years.

Finally, there are many libraries around to help with file uploads.  For example, [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/).

[Here is a good example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/ile-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp-java-web-tutorial-example.html) of how to put all of the above together.

Comment: I had tried using  Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
I couldn't get the result . It is returning null.

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain why `request.getPart("file")` also doesn't work.  You really do need to move that code out of a JSP and into a Servlet.  If you *really* want to keep it in a JSP, then you'll need to use Apache Commons FileUpload to handle the upload.